# Create a Range of Arrays from an Existing List of Arrays

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and having troubles getting this to work
I have an array called sentenceArray

```
val sentenceArray = arrayOfNulls<String>(7)
    sentenceArray[0] = "This is Sentence 0"
    sentenceArray[1] = "This is Sentence 1"
    sentenceArray[2] = "This is Sentence 2"
    sentenceArray[3] = "This is Sentence 3"
    sentenceArray[4] = "This is Sentence 4"
    sentenceArray[5] = "This is Sentence 5"
    sentenceArray[6] = "This is Sentence 6"
```

I have 2 Spinners called leftSpinner and rightSpinner and the arrays are from 0 to 6

```
val leftSpinnerArray = arrayOf("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
val rightSpinnerArray = arrayOf("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
```

The user selects a value for the left and right spinner and they are stored in selectedLeftSpinner and selectedRightSpinner

```
val selectedLeftSpinner = leftSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
val selectedRightSpinner = rightSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
```

What I am trying to do:

When the user selects 1 for the left Spinner and 3 on the right Spinner. I want the text view to display "This is Sentence 1, This is Sentence 2, This is Sentence 3" after a button is clicked

What happens:

Right now I have this code to generate an array from an existing array depending on the left and right spinner values but it does not work how I thought it would

```
val list = sentenceArray[selectedLeftSpinner.toInt()] to (sentenceArray[selectedRightSpinner.toInt()])
textView.text = list.toString()
```

When the user selects 1 for the left Spinner and 6 for the right Spinner
It shows "This is Sentence 1, This is Sentence 6" in the text view. Please Help! I tried replacing to to rangeTo but it errors out. I am not sure how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slice like this

```
val right=selectedRightSpinner.toInt()
val left=selectedLeftSpinner.toInt()
val list=sentenceArray.slice(left..right)
```